# how we can find connected device port numbers in node js?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, serial-port

I have used below code for node js. I want to know how we can get connected device port numbers in node js.

```
var serialport = require('serialport');
var serialportRef = serialport.SerialPort;
var portname = process.argv[2];

var UAQPort = new serialportRef(portname,{baudRate:9600,
parser:serialport.parsers.readline("\r\n")});

serialport.list(function (err, ports) {ports.forEach(function(port) {
ports.forEach(function(port) {
console.log(port.comName);
});
});
console.log(port.comName);});
UAQPort.on('open',onOpen);
UAQPort.on('data',onData);
function onOpen(){
console.log('connected port');}
function onData(){
console.log('deveice data '+data);}
```